# How can I get the specific worksheet in multiple workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

For example,
I have 10 classes' exam result.
Each class have their own workbook.
Each workbook have 3 worksheet : English Result, Math Result and Physics Result
How can I get all the Math Result from all the classes and combine it to 1 worksheet?

I tried to write an If-statement to do it but there are some errors.
The code I currently using can only get the result from the workbook that have only 1 worksheet.
Please help me!

Here are the codes I current using:

```
Sub CombineDataFiles()

Dim DataBook As Workbook, OutBook As Workbook
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet, OutSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetFiles As FileDialog
Dim MaxNumberFiles As Long, FileIdx As Long, _
    LastDataRow As Long, LastDataCol As Long, _
    HeaderRow As Long, LastOutRow As Long
Dim DataRng As Range, OutRng As Range

'initialize constants
MaxNumberFiles = 2001
HeaderRow = 1 'assume headers are always in row 1
LastOutRow = 1

'prompt user to select files
Set TargetFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With TargetFiles
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Multi-select target data files:"
    .ButtonName = ""
    .Filters.Clear
    .Show
End With

'error trap - don't allow user to pick more than 2000 files
' Can Modify By Changing the 2000


If TargetFiles.SelectedItems.Count > MaxNumberFiles Then
    MsgBox ("Too many files selected, please pick more than " & MaxNumberFiles & ". Exiting sub...")
    Exit Sub
End If


'set up the output workbook
Set OutBook = Workbooks.Add
Set OutSheet = OutBook.Sheets(1)

'loop through all files

For FileIdx = 1 To TargetFiles.SelectedItems.Count

    'open the file and assign the workbook/worksheet
    Set DataBook = Workbooks.Open(TargetFiles.SelectedItems(FileIdx))
    Set DataSheet = DataBook.ActiveSheet


    'identify row/column boundaries
    LastDataRow = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastDataCol = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    'if this is the first go-round, include the header
    If FileIdx = 1 Then
        Set DataRng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(HeaderRow, 1), DataSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
        Set OutRng = Range(OutSheet.Cells(HeaderRow, 1), OutSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
    'if this is NOT the first go-round, then skip the header
    Else
        Set DataRng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(HeaderRow + 1, 1), DataSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
        Set OutRng = Range(OutSheet.Cells(LastOutRow + 1, 1), OutSheet.Cells(LastOutRow + 1 + LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
    End If

    'copy the data to the outbook

    DataRng.Copy OutRng

    'close the data book without saving
    DataBook.Close False

    'update the last outbook row
    LastOutRow = OutSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    ' On Error Resume Next
        ' Range (A1;K100000).Select
        ' Selection

Next FileIdx

'let the user know we're done!
MsgBox ("Combined " & TargetFiles.SelectedItems.Count & " files!")

End Sub
```

Comment: show us what you tried and what you struggle with. I can definitly be done.

Comment: you need to show something; where the files are, more details. it is not enuogh.

Answer (score -1):

if I understand you right, you want to consolidate lists of data of the same shape (same number and order of columns) from different workbooks. Microsoft has a nice documentary on this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793964(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Please read the information in the site's [help] about answering questions on StackOverflow. What you've written better belongs in a Comment. Link-only responses are poor answers as links can break - the important information should be IN the Answer.

Comment: Thanks @CindyMeister ! I will do so. I am just getting started here and just want to help :) Should I delete the answer then?

Comment: Either copy the content as it stands to a comment and delete the answer - this is absolutely fine as a comment. OR consolidate the information pertinent to this question into your own answer (your own wording/interpretation & code) OR write a short summary about how it will help and copy/paste the *relevant* part of the article **with attribution** (and also the link). StackOverflow doesn't mind if you copy from somewhere else *if* you give full credit - important is that all info for the question is on-site. If you're unsure about what the person is really asking it's better to use a comment.

Comment: Further note: If a question is truly unclear, or the person asking obviously hasn't done any research / tried anything, then it's better to not write an Answer because 1) this is not a free coding-service or tutorial site; 2) questions that show no effort will get closed and deleted; 3) meaning that, in the end, you may have wasted your time. Just a tip - those are the kinds of things you learn when you've been around a while and read the Meta site :-)